# Python xlsxwriter return a value in a cell by xl_rowcol_to_cell?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

New to using XlsxWriter. I am trying to get the max of say zero and a value in a cell. Here is the my code:

```
import xlsxwriter
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell

tmp_val = max(0, xl_rowcol_to_cell(3, 1))
```

However, I keep getting the following error. seems xl_rowcol_to_cell(3, 1) just passes the address of a cell, but not the value in that cell. How can I fix this issue? Thanks!

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: looks like result you are getting from xl_rowcol_to_cell(3, 1) is a str, not int. You need to convert it to int first like ```int(xl_rowcol_to_cell(3, 1))```

Comment: @Biarys Thanks! I tried and still got this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'C8'

Comment: XlsxWriter can only write data. You can’t read data with it. Maybe try OpenPYXL which allows you to read and write.